# I would like to select the database from the string as i am a noob at coding

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I do not know how to get the String name from the database and would like some help from experts like you all Thank You in advance for helping.

```
try{
    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
    //Select from database below code
    String Name_=(/*what to put in here*/);
    String query=" select * from UserList where Name Like '%"+Name_+"%'  ";
    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    pst.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();                    
}
```

Comment: Name_ is not a suitable naming convention for a java variable. Use something simple such as name or nameToSelect. Then you can assign it to the name you want to select i.e. String name = "George"; Then the query will select all entries (users) named George.

Comment: as in i want to use a textbox to get the data on the database and i am using a keyreleased to get the data but this is to get from the database right ?

Comment: You'll want to learn [How to use Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as soon as possible. As to your question *"[The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)"* is what ever you are searching for BUT, you're not using the `PreparedStatement` properly

Comment: *"i am using a keyreleased"* - That's probably the wrong thing to do, you probably want to use an `ActionListener` or if you want a real time result a `DocumentListener` and Swing `Timer`

Comment: cause i have just starting learning object oriented programming and still unsure what to use and i am still learning thank you all for the replies i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You're missing capital letters in order to talk with your db.

Comment: You mean the query ?